# Get Item ID From Context Menu

Tags: java, android

hey people,
I am trying to get the id of the item, in this case a table row, that was long pressed to bring up the context menu.  This is my code so far.

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                                ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
  super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
  MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
  inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
  switch (item.getItemId()) {
      case R.id.delete:

          deleteitem(id); //ID of item should be passed to method deleteitem
          Toast.makeText(this, "delete",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
      default:
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
  }
}
```

As you can see I need the id of the table row to pass to another method.  I have tried using info however it is always null.  Obviously I am missing something here so hopefully you'll be able to point me in the right direction.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [`AdapterContextMenuInfo.id`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo.html#id) field.

Answer (score 0):

[AdapterContextMenuInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo.htm) has both an id and position fields that correspond to the item in the adapter that was selected.

So in your code replace your deleteItem with this.

```
deleteItem(info.id);
```

should work.

Comment: yh but for some reason info is always null

Comment: @crazyfool did you call registerForContextMenu() and pass in your ListView?

Comment: I'm not using a list view, I used each table row so I used: registerForContextMenu(tablerow)

Comment: @crazyfool
Having the same problem were info is coming up as null. You find a solution to this?